# People cant join me on minecraft xbox one edition but i can join them

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I'm on Minecraft Xbox one edition and I'm having trouble with having my friend joining my world. When he tries to join my world it just tells him he can't connect to my world, it happens with all my worlds and weirdly enough I can join him but he can't join *me*. I've had two people in total try to join and it's the same. We used to play all the time but one day randomly it stopped working. Can anyone help or has this happened to anyone else? I've tried looking in settings for anything I need to change and I should be fine but nope

Comment: Are you really playing [Minecraft:Xbox One Edition](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Xbox_One_Edition), a game that was discontinued in 2017?

Answer (score 1):

It may be a [NAT issue](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/networking/nat-error-solution).

---

First, we’ll want to check your current NAT type. To do this:

1. Scroll left from Home to open the guide.
2. Select Settings.
3. Select All Settings.
4. Select Network.

[image: NAT Types]

---

The webpage linked above provides a nice walkthrough on fixing it so that it works. If it seems to be the problem (based on its current setting and the chart above), take a look at the webpage.